# Confusing on Character Streams sample code in Oracle website

Tags: java

As I read following from the [Oracle website](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html), I get that the int variable holds a character value in its last 16 bits from `inputStream.read()`.

So does it always waste 2 bytes ?

> CopyCharacters is very similar to CopyBytes. The most important 
>   difference is that CopyCharacters uses FileReader and FileWriter for 
>   input and output in place of FileInputStream and FileOutputStream. 
>   Notice that both CopyBytes and CopyCharacters use an int variable to 
>   read to and write from. However, in CopyCharacters, the int variable 
>   holds a character value in its last 16 bits; in CopyBytes, the int 
>   variable holds a byte value in its last 8 bits.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CopyCharacters {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileReader inputStream = null;
        FileWriter outputStream = null;

        try {
            inputStream = new FileReader("xanadu.txt");
            outputStream = new FileWriter("characteroutput.txt");

            int c;
            while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(c);
            }
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I might be mistaken but I believe it would be useful if you had a 32bit encoding as default encoding, such as UTF-32.

Comment: @Aaron - `Reader.read()` is going to return either a UTF-16 code unit (or -1) irrespective of the encoding of the stream that you are reading.  That's the whole point of a `Reader`.  It *decodes* the input encoding to a standard representation: Unicode code-points in UTF-16 representation.

Comment: @StephenC makes sense, thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So does it always waste 2 bytes ?

Ermm ... yes.  Either 2 bytes in the `Reader` case or 3 bytes in the `InputStream` case.

This wastage is necessary for the following reasons:

1. Both `InputStream.read()` and `Reader.read()` need to return a value to represent the "end of stream".  As the javadocs say:

   > `InputStream.read()`: Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned.
   >
   > `Reader.read()`: Returns the character read, as an integer in the range 0 to 65535 (0x00-0xffff), or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached.

   The extra end-of-stream value means that the return type of `read()` cannot be (respectively) `byte` or `char`.  (See also the last reason ...)
2. It turns out that the "wasted" 2 or 3 bytes are of no consequence.  Even a trivial Java program is going to use megabytes of memory.  (Indeed, even a trivial C program is going to use tens or hundreds of kilobytes of memory ... if you account for the library code that they use.)
3. Returning a `byte` or `char` probably wouldn't save memory anyway.  In a typical modern systems, local variables (even `byte` and `char`) are stored word aligned on the stack.  This is done because accessing memory with a word aligned address is typically faster.
4. Replacing the `-1` with an exception would be inefficient in another way.  Throwing and catching exceptions in Java is significantly more expensive than a simple test for `-1`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer above, especially for the point 3 & 4.